# Disable all controls and links on redirection

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, asp.net-controls

I need information and code. What I want to achieve is that when user click on a link or control, the rest of the controls and links will become disabled. So user can't click on any link or control while page is redirecting.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can put a panel and inside of it put all the controls and disable it when you redirect:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Pan1" runat="server" >
      ...
</asp:Panel >
```

And before redirect disable it:

```
Pan1.Enable = False
```

Comment: and what about menu links. How can I disable them

Comment: @fwd I tried it with different controls and it was working fine. For the menu link just `Menu1.Enable = False` it won't be disable for some reason inside the panel

Answer (score 0):

Place the controls withing a div, and on redirection, change the CSS of the div.
If you wish to do the same from code behind then please use

```
<div ID="DivID" runat="server"/>
```

and then you can access the same from code behind.

Comment: and what about menu links. How can I disable them?